# Array if size over 2 set array to []

Tags: ruby, arrays

```
@ad = [2, 5, 5]
if @ad.size < 2
  @ad = []
end
@ad # => [2, 5, 5]
```

Why is `@ad` not `[]`? I want to store the last two records found in an array and if they are the same, it should find a new record.

Comment: `3 < 2` -> `false`. Moreover, what you explain with words has little resemblance with the code you show (at least I can't see it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is @ad not []?

Why *would* it be? Your code is *extremely* basic, and it says "if @ad has less than two items, set it to an empty array". As you clearly show, @ad *doesn't* have less than two items, it has three items. Does three seem less than two to you?

If you're tying to find the number of *unique* items, you need ot use `.uniq`, but it still won't be *less* than two, it will be exactly two, and so you *still* won't enter the `if` condition.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you got the `>` wrong.

Don’t worry, that happens to the best.

There is an even more terse way of writing your code, using a trailing if.

```
@ad = [2, 5, 5]
@ad = [] if @ad.size > 2
@ad # => []
```